# How to determine path to project folder in .Net?

Tags: .net, path, xslt

I have a project folder called XSL which contains xsl files used for transforming xml. I use the following code to fetch an xsl file:

```
string html = @"c:\temp\export.html";
XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
Uri uri = new Uri(@"XSL\ToHtml.xsl", UriKind.Relative);
transform.Transform(CurrentXmlFile, html);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(html);
```

This works ok when debugging but when I deploy using clickonce and install it, I get an error - 'Could not find part of the path {my user documents path}\XSL\ToHtml.xsl'. It really needs to be looking in {installation folder}\XSL\ToHtml.xsl.

What must I do to correctly reference this path?

Comment: Are you sure there is such path under the root folder of your app after it was deployed?

Comment: @andrew. You're right. It is missing. Why? File is set to Resource,  'Copy if newer'

Comment: I changed it to **Content, Copy if newer** and it works! Thanks Andrew

Answer (score 3):

As already stated in DSO's answer, you should not use or implicitly depend of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` when you want the directory where your application executable or assemblies are located.

However I would use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` instead of relying on the location of the currently executing assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are based off the current directory (Environment.CurrentDirectory), which your app has no control over.  If you want to base a path off your app's install folder use this:

```
string file = Path.Combine(
    System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
    @"XSL\ToHtml.xsl");
```

Comment: I'm sorry to -1 this, but I just discovered that this approach breaks when running as a non-admin and a user clicks "Run As Admin" on a shortcut.  For some bizarre reason GetExecutingAssembly() ends up returning the location of the shortcut rather than the location of the currently executing assembly.  Instead use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.  That consistently works.